# chroot and hyperos on ArchLinux?

Tags: linux, chroot, squashfs, cpio, tinycore

[hyperos](http://hyperos.io/) is a fork of [tinycorelinux](http://tinycorelinux.net/) Can I run hyperos in a chroot? How can I create an ISO image from files on repo? Is this possible? Which steps should I follow?

Comment: Probably (but not the kernel). Consider also docker.